# Single Access point vs Wireless Bridge in pair

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet, wireless-bridge

I have been looking everywhere for some answers but wow there is not a single one.

So the question in theory is actually pretty simple. If i for example have a Tv box that requires ethernet port and doesn't have wifi, every technical shop i would go to would insist that you have to buy a wireless bridge(same as homeplugs) in PAIR. That means i have to put one of the wireless bridge into the main router and the other one into the device that needs ethernet and then sync the wireless bridges together.
ROUTER->(lan)Wireless Bridge->(Wifi)Wireless Bridge->(lan)Tv

Since i am a rebel, i thought that makes no sense and i bought one SINGLE  wifi extender with a simple ethernet port on its side, its basically an access point if i wire it or a repeater without wiring. And to my shock it worked beautifully, so now not only do i have a single wireless bridge but also an extra accesspoint for my other devices to connect also wireless.

So by doing this i essentially cut the cost in half by only buying one extender and still succeeded in making the bridge.
ROUTER->(wifi)extender->(lan)tv

I believe getting a firm answer would be able to make many people save alot of money if this indeed works. So what do you guys think is the reason all of the technical shops insisted that i had two buy bridges in pair and none believed that one extender/repeater would do all the job?? I mean maybe if i were using say for example an IP Tv Box from my ISP would using my method with a single extender maybe stop working after awhile?

Comment: Think the issue is you are dealing with non-technical sales people who may be told to upsell, etc.  This is typical of big box stores, places like Best Buy, etc.  Do your own research, ask here, etc. and just use the store to buy from, not get "how to do it" advice from.

Comment: @Strongpanda, kudos to you for questioning their technical knowledge. If I understood correctly, you want to wirelessly connect a wired device? As you discovered so yourself, you only need 1 device to do so. That device connects wirelessly and will bridge the connection onto it's wired port, allowing the wired device to "wireleslly" connect to the network (example: Ubiquiti airGateway). I guess as ivanivan mentioned, it's just a way to sell more junk or lack of knowledge.